# Which JAR do I need for lucene.search.spell in lucene 8.10.1?

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene 8.10.1. I am unable to use lucene.search.spell.LuceneDictionary. I don't know which JAR to add to my classpath. I have added core, queryparsers, analyser-common and the demo jar files.

But I get the following: [image]

[image]
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the "Suggest" module.

Using Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-suggest</artifactId>
    <version>8.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or, if you want the specific JAR, it is downloadable from here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-suggest/8.10.1

Click on the `jar` link on that page.

---

A good place to track this down is this overview page:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_10_1/index.html

In this page you will see a list of the main API packages with a brief summary. The "suggest" package link leads to the JavaDoc page:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_10_1/suggest/index.html

There you can see which classes are available.

Finally, a search in [the Maven repo home page](https://mvnrepository.com/) for "lucene suggest" leads to the Maven details mentioned above.